# SQL Server - Inner and Outer join together

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, outer-join

Need some help in writing the SQL query for SQL Server. I have following data model with three tables

Table 1

```
Seq   ID   Name
1    1234   Abc
2    4567   Pqr
3    7890   Xyz
```

Table 2

```
Seq Table1Id Table3Seq
1    1234       1
2    1234       2
3    7890       3
```

Table 3

```
Seq  Status
1    Rejected
2    Accepted
3    Pending
```

My requirement is something like below. I want to have all the records from Table 1 with the LATEST status from Table 3 if it exists. So, as we can see for Id `1234`, there are two records matching in Table 3 (via Table 2), however I want the latest which is Accepted. But there is a record in Table 1 `4567` which doesn't have any record in Table 2, so I am fine to show empty against the Status.

```
Number    Name     Status
1234      Abc      Accepted
4567      Pqr      
7890      Xyz      Pending
```

I guess, we might need to use Outer and Inner join together, however so far I am unable to find the right query. When I try to just use outer join using `MAX`, it still gives me two records against `1234` and when I use inner join, then I don't get record  `4567` in the output.

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Comment: How do you now the second record for 1234 is the latest? is there a datetime field or something?

Comment: Hi @haytem, value against the higher sequence number in Table 3 is assumed to be latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.ID, a.Name, c.Status
from table1 a
left outer join (select max(b.seq) AS SEQ, b.table1id from table2 b group by b.table1id) t2 on a.id = t2.table1id
left outer join table2 t2b on t2.seq = t2b.seq and t2.table1id = t2b.table1id
left outer join table3 c on t2b.table3seq = c.seq
```

There are probably more efficient ways to do it, but this will give you the results you're after. Basically joins table 1 to a subset of table 2 getting the max sequence of each record, then join to table2 again to get the link to table 3, then join to table3 to get the status.

All joins are left outer so you get your pqr result coming back with a null status.

Comment: Thanks mate for quick help. My problem is solved. I actually tried using MAX() too, but unfortunately I had missed the GROUP BY clause.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using two joins:

```
SELECT Number, Name, Status FROM
        (SELECT Table1.ID AS Number, Table1.Name, Table3.Status, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Table1.Number ORDER BY table3.Seq DESC) AS RN
        FROM Table1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID=Table2.Table1ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.seq=table2.Table3Seq)MyTable
        WHERE MyTable.RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this in SQL Server is using `outer apply`.  This method often has the best performance:

```
select t1.*, t3.status
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select top 1 t3.*
      from table2 t2 join
           table3 t3
           on t2.table3seq = t3.seq
      where t1.id = t2.table1id
      order by t2.id desc
     ) t3;
```

The appropriate indexes are `table2(table1id, table3seq, id)` and `table3(seq, status)`.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon.. Will try this as well and see if gives me desired output with better performance.